# Reference request: interesting writing on the topic of descriptivism and prescriptivism?

Tags: style-manuals

It seems to me that descriptivism versus prescriptivism is a false dichotomy. On another stackexchange site, I was [recently moved to interject](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/140784/1482), in a hot and heavy dispute over split infinitives: --

> Even someone who thinks prescriptivist grammar is fine can think that a certain instance of prescriptivist grammar is nonsense. Good prescriptivism consists of making the language more beautiful, rich, precise, and expressive by emulating what's best about the best writing -- which has nothing to do with obeying a 19th century grammar book that codified already-obsolete 16th-18th century usage. http://merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/to-boldly-split-infinitives

This sort of thing makes me want to write a manifesto, but we all know that manifesto-writing is a sin, right up there with adultery, kicking dogs, and writing "it's" for "its." It may also be a sin because reinventing the wheel is a sin.

Reference request: Can anyone point me to influential or well written discussions of this topic that would allow me to abstain from this sin? That is, I would like to see a fervent, fire-breathing Fidel Castro defense of what I've described above in vague terms as "good" prescriptivism. I would also be happy to see a well argued explanation of why my notion of good prescriptivism is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is resource request

Comment: You could look at one of the introductory chapters in Garner's _Modern American Usage_. It's titled "_Making Peace in the  Language Wars_" and attempts a reconciliation between descriptivists and prescriptivists, such as Garner himself. You could also look at an opening chapter in the descriptivist _Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language_ (_"Prescriptivism, tradition and the justification of grammars"_), which covers the same ground.

Comment: No, there is no such thing as "good prescriptivism".

Comment: "Can anyone point me to influential or well written discussions of this topic" better on https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let's face it, folks -- there **is** no interesting writing on that topic because that's not a real topic. Anybody who's educated knows that there is no good prescriptivism, just like there's no good racism.

Comment: @JohnLawler, a true and complete **description** of prescriptivism must acknowledge that most prescriptivists do not see themselves as in any way akin to racists (notwithstanding the fact that some descriptivists see them that way). Implying that there are no educated well-intended, thoughtful people on the prescriptivist side of the descriptivism-prescriptivism spectrum is at odds with descriptivism.

Comment: The point is that there isn't a spectrum. There are people who tell other people how they should speak (always "just like us"). There is no "true and complete **description** of prescriptivism" because it doesn't exist; there is no speech group and there is no consensus. Descriptions would collapse over terminology.

Comment: @JohnLawler, don't your comments also amount to telling 'other people [prescriptivists] how they should speak (always "just like us[, descriptivists]'?

Comment: Not at all. Just stop telling people how to talk (unless someone asks you, of course). It's rude and it's ignorant. No more need be said.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for a resource. // Hyper-descriptivism = chaos, anarchy. Hyper-prescriptivism = fossilisation, elitism, an arrogance that thinks that 1600s / 1810s / 1880s / 1950s ... English-as-taught-by-Gradgrind is canonical.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about a defense of either or an explanation of either that follows the plan of your desires. But a not too old book review in the New Yorker covers them quickly:

> [The English Wars, by Joan Acocella](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/05/14/the-english-wars)

Comment: That particular article [was discussed in the literature](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3952) as a beautiful example of confused but angry anti-descriptivists.

Answer (score -1):

David Foster Wallace wrote “Tense Present” on this topic for Harper’s.

https://harpers.org/wp-content/uploads/HarpersMagazine-2001-04-0070913.pdf

The question is, indeed, a resource request; and a personal preference issue as well.

Comment: Resource requests go on meta.

Comment: Another very confused but beautifully written article. Wallace was an elitist and a great writer, who felt everyone should write for his tastes. Not everyone agrees.